# block not gets called

Tags: magento-1.9

I am having a config.xml file in my module `Adept/Wallets/etc` as -

```
<frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <wallets>
                    <file>wallets.xml</file>
                </wallets>
            </updates>
        </layout>
</frontend>

...

    <global>
            <blocks>
                <wallets>
                    <class>Adept_Wallets_Block_Walletrequest</class>
                </wallets>            
            </blocks>
    </global>
```

my layout file wallets.xml  is -

```
<wallets_index_wallethistory>
        <update handle="customer_account" />
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="page/html" name="walletrequest" template="wallets/wallethistory.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </wallets_index_wallethistory>
```

I have created block class in  `Adept/Wallets/Block/Walletrequest.php`

```
<?php
class Adept_Wallets_Block_Walletrequest extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    public function __construct() 
    {  echo "here2"; die;
        parent::__construct();
        $collection = Mage::getModel('wallets/sellerrequest')->getCollection();
        $this->setCollection($collection);        
    } 

    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
            parent::_prepareLayout();

            $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html_pager', 'custom.pager');
            $pager->setAvailableLimit(array(5=>5,10=>10,20=>20,'all'=>'all'));
            $pager->setCollection($this->getCollection());
            $this->setChild('pager', $pager);
            $this->getCollection()->load();
            return $this;
    }

    public function getPagerHtml()
    {
            return $this->getChildHtml('pager');
    } 
}
```

I expect to execute this and display message and die when page loads, but it doesn't. 
I am not getting what went wrong.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are lot of issue in your model.

**Issue 1:** You have not define block `class at config.xml`

```
<global>
            <blocks>
                <wallets>
                    <class>Adept_Wallets_Block_Walletrequest</class>
                </wallets>            
            </blocks>
    </global>
```

**Should be**

```
<global>
            <blocks>
                <wallets>
                    <class>Adept_Wallets_Block</class>
                </wallets>            
            </blocks>
    </global>
```

**Issue 2:** On Layout file you have not call the block type is should `wallets/Walletrequest`  to `page/html`

Answer (score 2):

In your config.xml file. You have declared block base class name as Adept_Wallets_Block_Walletrequest

```
<global>
        <blocks>
            <wallets>
                <class>Adept_Wallets_Block_Walletrequest</class>
            </wallets>            
        </blocks>
</global>
```

it should be Adept_Wallets_Block .since you are mentioning base class name.

Answer (score 1):

your code should be as follows

```
<global>
    <blocks>
        <wallets>
            <class>Adept_Wallets_Block</class>
        </wallets>
    </blocks>
</global>
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you are using page/html type block if you are making your custom one your xml tag should be as below

```
 <reference name="content">
            <block type="wallets/walletrequest" name="walletrequest" template="wallets/wallethistory.phtml" />
        </reference>
```

Try to change **type="wallets/walletrequest"** and see.

hope this will solve your issue.